# Software to click anywhere on the screen without mouse

Tags: windows, mouse, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that I can move the mouse using the keyboard.
But I am searching something that work faster.

Some years ago I had a software that make a table on the screen, that give any place a number, and give me the way to click it.

Do you know about it?
Maybe chrome extension?

Comment: Since you say "Chrome extension", do you only want it to work in the Chrome browser, or in all Windows programs?

Comment: I am willing for recommendation to Chrome extension or window program.(Now I am using Vimium but it is not let me click anywhere on the screen, only on links)

Comment: What else do you want to click on? And what should happen when you do?

Comment: What would you like as input device? Keyboard only? Or also Touch, Gestures by Hand, Eyeball tracking...?

Comment: Only keyboard. fast way to click on any point in the screen

Comment: OK, you asked about software, but have you considered a keyboard with a trackpoint: https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/lenovo-thinkpad-compact-weiteres-notebook-zubehoer-2481078?pcscpId=8&gclid=CKzMk7WDy8MCFamWtAodpkgALg

Comment: It's cheap and easy to add touch screen to an existing monitor. Just search AliExpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a script in AutoHotkey to do this:
https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=51201

When you press NumKeyEnter, this script builds then displays a 26*26 grid of buttons (actually AHK edit controls), labelled AA-ZZ, overlaying the whole screen.

You can then emulate a mouse-click (or a touchscreen 'touch') at any of those 676 locations by entering the coordinates, as displayed on each button, as keyboard shortcuts

Comment: [link-only answers are not good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/230282) since it'll be invalid when the link dies. It actually has happened with autohotkey website before and tons of scripts went to trash without any backup. You should copy the script and paste here instead

Answer (score 2):

1. Grid control of Windows, but you [control the clicking with your
   voice,](http://assistivetechnology.about.com/od/PointersandMice/qt/Navigate-Web-Browsers-Via-Voice-With-Nuance-Dragon-Mouse-Grids.htm) not the keyboard.
2. Similar question, but [the three main answers are voice controlled](https://superuser.com/questions/452413/virtual-mouse-using-the-keyboard).
3. An edit of one question, however, pointed to a dead website with software that was allegedly what you wanted. A quick Google search found **[Mouse Grid 1.0](http://www.freewarefiles.com/Mouse-Grid_program_32326.html), which allegedly does what you want.**

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for "Mousless Browsing": https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/mouseless-browsing/.

[image: Example Screenshot from the author]

I used that a while ago and it was very cool. It adds a small icon to every link. By keying in that shortcut, the browser follows the link.

Comment: I would like to click anywhere on the screen. not just links

Answer (score 0):

> But I am searching something that work faster.

Windows' [mouse key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys) already has that ability. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to speed up. You can also increase the acceleration to make it reach high speed more quickly. Additionally you can increase the normal speed

[image: mouse key]

These speed-control option have also been available long ago in previous Windows versions

[image: mouse key in older Windows]

[How to Use the Keyboard to Control the Mouse Cursor in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/07_other_settings.png)